# How to get the Name from table and pass to VIEW, through Tempdata in .net MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Model Class is Student
db is object of StudentContext Class
In Line 8, I want to print Student's Name, along with the TempData["DeleteMessage"], which I have deleted

[image]
'''

```
public ActionResult Delete(Student s)
        {
            db.Entry(s).State = EntityState.Deleted;
            int a = db.SaveChanges();
            string nameof = s.Name;
            if(a > 0)
            {
                TempData["DeleteMessage"] = "Student's Data Deleted.";
                
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                TempData["DeleteMessage"] = "Student's Data Not Deleted.";
            }
            return View();  
        }
```

'''

Comment: What name do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You could use string interpolation, but you would also have to pass that on to the action you are redirecting to (not sure what your TempData is, so the information could be lost on the redirect):

```
public ActionResult Delete(Student s)
{
    db.Entry(s).State = EntityState.Deleted;
    int a = db.SaveChanges();

    if(a > 0)
    {
        TempData["DeleteMessage"] = $"Student {s.Name}'s data has been deleted.";
        
        // Make sure your "index" action has the parameter deleteMessage
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { deleteMessage = TempData["DeleteMessage"] });
    }
    else
    {
        TempData["DeleteMessage"] = "Student's Data Not Deleted.";
    }

    return View();  
}
```

If the student record's name property had the name "Bob", then the delete message (assuming a > 0) would be "Student Bob's data has been deleted"